# Splitting a big permutation

Tags: excel, vba, permutation

I have two columns, with 40.000 rows.

I need to do permutation between the two columns and analyse the results.

I know that doing a permutation of 40.000 x 40.000 will give huge results. I believe I can narrow the results by adding conditions, so I can ignore some of the inputs.

Still I will get results much bigger than the row limit of the sheet.

How can I split the results so I can create a new sheet / new workbook, every 1.000.000 results?

My permutation loop:

```
Sub Permutation()
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, N As Long

    N = 1
    For i = 1 To 40000
            For k = 1 To 40000
                Cells(N, 3) = Cells(i, 1) & Cells(k, 2)
                N = N + 1
            Next k
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You mention adding conditions, what are they?

Comment: the conditions will be mainly :
- ignoring doubles if all the parameters of cell A = Cell B
- proceeding only when some parameters in cell A matches cell B

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For huge data, use a database (e.g. SQL.Server, MySQL , ...) and query with SQL.(Almost no limit on size). Or try Office x64 what increases the data linit of Excel

Comment: Unless you reduce the 40000 BEFORE running Permutation, you still need to process 1.6 Billion permutations... whether or not you then "Save" them. I believe to get a reasonable running time you will Have to pull the data into arrays and manipulate it "in memory" as that's far faster than looping through cells. However, even arrays have memory limitations I think this may exceed. (Frankly I wonder if this is more for a "maths" program like Sage or Mathematica)

Comment: You could add a `counter` variable which starts at 1, and it increases by 1 when N reaches 1.000.000 (so `counter` = 2), and then becomes 3 when N reaches 2.000.000, and have it so that `Cells(N, 3) = Cells(i, 1) & Cells(k, 2)` instead says `Sheets(counter).Cells(N, 3) = Sheets(counter).Cells(i,1) & Sheets(counter).Cells(k,2)`. Just make sure you have enough sheets already created before running the macro. So, `counter` is a reference to the sheet index.

Answer (score 1):

What ever you want to analyse, you can't use all results from the permutation in one step. Like Stax wrote, you would have 1.6 billion single values. Even if you wrote 1 million per sheet you need 1600 sheets. For every character in a value you need 1.6GB memory. I don't know your mashine but if every value has a length of 3 characters you need 4.8GB memory only for your data. Excel 32 bit can only handle 4GB. There is no way with Excel in that way.

But if you don't need all values at the same time you can work in another way. You have 40k blocks with 40k values. Your second column is in every 40k block the same. You must only switch the first part of a 40k permutation block to the value of the first column you need at that time. It's like counting. Nobody writes down all numbers to calculate something. You simply use the required number section.

(To long as a comment)